# Most efficient way to log curl responses (html)

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I have a php script that uses curl to login to a site.
I need to log all http responses so that I can track errors.

Problem: each login consists of multiple http requests/responses which totals about 26 000 lines. Saving that in a textfile makes it really hard for me to find what I need.

Would it be reasonable to log everything in a mysql database?

Clarification:
Is it a good idea to store large html-documents in a mysql database?
Are there any problems involved in storing html/javascript/css in mysql?
What datatype would be suitable?

Comment: How would we be able to tell whether logging into a database would be better than a text file? Please clarify your question.

Comment: I haven't tried it out myself, but check out MySQL's `ARCHIVE` storage engine. Note that you can't delete individual records form an ARCHIVE table, but you can drop the entire table's contents. It doesn't support indexes either, which is not a huge deal with simple logging tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can log all that text into any file, and then use grep to filter whatever you need

If you will write all data to database, it will cause even higher load on your hardware then just log everything into file

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context.

A filesystem is usually a much better place to store medium to large data sets which you're not going to update / search inside frequently. OTOH PHP (and most languages come to think of it) don't suport sophisticated locking mechanisms to handle concurrent access to files gracefully.

> each login consists of multiple http requests/responses which totals about 26 000 lines

How many requests?

> Saving that in a textfile makes it really hard for me to find what I need.

Why aren't you extracting the bits you need when you get the HTTP responses?

Why do you think that dumping it into a database will help you extract the bits you need?

Comment: Each login consists of about 10 requests. I am extracting the bits I need, but sometimes when the site changes my script just can't find the bits. Therefore I thought it would be good to store all the output from the site.

Comment: Dumping the requests in a database would make it easier to organize requests/responses by sessions/users/steps-of-loging-in-process.

Comment: Never thought of using directories? An index?